# ERROR: Failed building wheel for cryptography

Tags: python, django

Hey guys I was installing "channels"
"pip install channels"
but I received this Error.

```
Failed building wheel for cryptography
  Running setup.py clean for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography
Could not build wheels for cryptography which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

What should I do now?